# How can I make an api call within the map method that renders dom nodes?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, material-ui

I am trying to use a promise inside of my map method but the return from the promise is showing [object Promise]. But in the code where I made the promise, I return the response.data.itemThatIWant. How can I get the actual results from promise within my map method?

I tried calling promise outside of the map and storing results in array and then mapping over that array inside of map but then I get duplicates of everything.

Here is the code that is trying to call promise in map

```
<Grid className={classes.listGrid} container>
                {favoriteProviders.map((provider, index) =>

                  <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} key={index} value={index}>

                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                      <Grid container direction="row">
                        <img src={`https://animasds-content.azureedge.net/provider-images/${getImagePath(provider.doc_id)}?${Date.now()}`}
                          alt="doctor" style={{ margin: 5, height: 60, borderRadius: 5 }} />
```

Here is the promise I created:

```
import axios from "axios";

async function getImagePath(id) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/provider/image/img`, { id },
            {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}`
                }
            })
        return res.data.ImagePath
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
export default getImagePath;
```

If I put console.log(res.data.ImagePath) i get what I want here, but in map, I just get [object Promise]

I expect an image to display based on the information from each item in array that I am mapping over.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be `<img src={"https://animasds-content.azureedge.net/provider-images/${await getImagePath(provider.doc_id)}?${Date.now()}"}`

but i guess render can't be async so you'd have to do that in some lifecycle method and set it in state maybe.

So i suggest:

```
class ApiImg extends Component {

  state = {};

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ url: await getImagePath(this.props.id)});
  }

  render() { 
    {this.state.url &&
       <img src={`https://animasds-content.azureedge.net/provider-images/${this.state.url}?${Date.now()}`}
         alt="doctor" style={{ margin: 5, height: 60, borderRadius: 5 }} />
    }
  }
}
```

using it like that:

```
<Grid container direction="row">
    <ApiImg id={provider.doc_id} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the state of that **getImagePath**, when it's not ready, you should render something else, like

```
{this.state.images[imageId] ? <img src={`https://animasds-content.azureedge.net/provider-images/${this.state.images[imageId]}?${Date.now()}`}
                          alt="doctor" style={{ margin: 5, height: 60, borderRadius: 5 }} /> : <Something to indicate not ready />
```

And you can handle the ready state when you get the result, like

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const response = await getImagePath(XXXXXX);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ images: {id: json} });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```